# t("website_title") nil after moving from Heroku Bamboo to Cedar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rails-i18n, cedar

I just moved my working Heroku app [from Bamboo to Cedar](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar-migration), and now it crashes with:

```
Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (4.6ms)
ActionView::Template::Error (no implicit conversion of nil into String):
8:          <%= t("website_title") %>
```

As you can see, `t("website_title")` seems to be `nil`, despite the fact that `website_title` is still in `config/locales/en.yml` as usual:

```
en:
  website_title: Cats (All about cats)
```

Is it a known issue when moving from Bamboo to Cedar?
Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `heroku logs` was showing log lines in non-chronological order, which lead me to think the problem was line 8, but in fact it was this problem:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9619

Which I solved as explained by dvdplm there.